# How to set record rule for account move to show user own records and their saleteams member records Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo-15, record-rules

Is this possible to do this by record rule?

Example:

user A have saleteam with member B,C,D. A is the leader of this team.

so if we login to A, and go to account.move, we can see records of A,B,C,D.

if we login to b, we only see B records.

Thanks you.

Note: Other solution are good too, no need to be record rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jainesh Shah(Aktiv Software)

I've found the answer, which is use the search_read() function:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, models, api, _


class AccountMove(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.move'

    def search_read(self, domain=None, fields=None, offset=0, limit=None, order=None):
        # find list members of sale team which leaded by current user (current user is leader of this sale team)
        sale_teams = self.env['crm.team'].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.user.id)]).mapped('member_ids')

        # if current user is in group crm_account_move_restrict_records and also the leader of a team
        # then we will show all data of this user and members of the team that this user is leading
        if self.env.user.has_group('z_crm_contract_for_baan.crm_account_move_restrict_records'):
            if sale_teams:
                # add domain
                # get data by team members
                domain += ['|', ('user_id', 'in', sale_teams.ids)]
            # add domain
            # get data by current user
            domain += [('user_id', '=', self.env.user.id)]
        return super(AccountMove, self).search_read(domain=domain, fields=fields, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
```

Thanks you all for helping, especially Jainesh Shah(Aktiv Software).